# unable to turn off display

Tags: display, shutdown

I'm a bit of a newbi when It comes to Ubuntu. But I've installed Ubuntu Server 17.04.

I'm running it on a laptop and I want to turn off the display.
I'm running the commands with my admin account with root access.

I've tried the following with xset..

```
xset dpms force off
```

Which gives me the following error message..

```
xset:  unable to open display ""
```

I've also tried using vbetool with the following code..

```
sudo vbetool dpms off
```

which gives me the following error message..

```
Real mode call failed
```

After googeling around I found a guy that did a Python script

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import time
import subprocess
from Xlib import X
from Xlib.display import Display

display = Display(':0')
#display = Display('0')
root = display.screen().root
root.grab_pointer(True,
    X.ButtonPressMask | X.ButtonReleaseMask | X.PointerMotionMask,
    X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeAsync, 0, 0, X.CurrentTime)
root.grab_keyboard(True,
    X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeAsync, X.CurrentTime)

subprocess.call('xset dpms force off'.split())
p = subprocess.Popen('gnome-screensaver-command -i'.split())
time.sleep(1)

while True:
print display.next_event()
p.terminate()
break
```

and it gives me the following error message..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script.py", line 8, in <module>
    display = Display(':0')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
    display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.socket = connect.get_socket(name, host, displayno)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 78, in get_socket
    return getattr(mod, modname).get_socket(dname, host, dno)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 91, in get_socket
    raise error.DisplayConnectionError(dname, str(val))
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": [Errno 2] No such file or directory
administrator@readytoserver:~/Scripts$
```

any ideas?

Would apprieciate some help from you guys since I feel this is a bit beyond me.

Comment: Well, not really true. If I start the laptop the display is constantly on and displaying a "login" prompt. I don't see how I can run the computer with the monitor off? besides the monitor works perfectly fine to issue commands to the server from even though I mostly use Putty and my other computers.

Comment: All the code you refer to is for the GUI, which you don't have.

Comment: Ok, I see. But still, there's a monitor plugged into the laptop running ubuntu server and I ought to be able to deactivate the monitor ? Should I try a different approach and use bios?

Answer (score 1):

This issue was not present on 16.04. The LCD automatically turned off on the laptop after period of time but if lid closed went to sleep.

I resolved this issue for my Lenovo T410 as after I installed 18.04 and upgraded to 18.04.1 the LCD turned off unless I closed the lid of the laptop and that puts it to sleep.

Now I can lower the lid till the LCD shuts off or completely close the lid and it doesn't go to sleep.

Resolution is to edit file: `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

```
HandleSuspendKey=ignore
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
```